# Adjuntar varios archivos y enviarlos por phpmailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

¿Cómo puedo adjuntar varios archivos (más de dos archivos) mediante un input file con la librería PHPMailer?

Hasta el momento he podido hacer que se envíe, pero requiero agregar más archivos adjuntos.

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth= true;
//$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
$mail->Host ="dominio";
$mail->Username="notificaciones@dominio.org.mx";
$mail->Password ="@@@@@@@@";
$mail->Port = 25;
$mail->From = $email;
$mail->FromName="Notificaciones - ".$mercancia_para;
$mail->AddAddress(Core::$user->email);
$mail->AddAddress("correo1@dominio.org.mx");
//$mail->AddCC("correx@gmail.com");
$mail->AddCC("correo2@dominio.org.mx");
$mail->IsHTML(true);

$mail->Subject = $asunto;
$mail->Body = $contenido;
$mail->WordWrap = 50;
$mail->MsgHTML($contenido);

if($mail->Send()){
    $respuesta ="<h2 style='color:#0A7A39;'>Solicitud Realizada con exito!</h2>,  <br> <strong>¡Se ha generado el folio de solicitud: ".$folio_ingreso." y se envio notificación via email!</strong>";
    echo $respuesta;
}else{
    $respuesta ="<div class='alert alert-danger'><strong>Error!!!</strong>  Intenta mas tarde! </div>".$mail->ErrorInfo;
    echo $respuesta;
}
```

Hasta este momento logro enviar correos, solo que ahora quiero adjuntar varios archivos en el envío.

Comment: varios archivos? o de cualquier tipo?

Comment: Gracias ByGroD, Varios archivos es decir que a traves de un input file, selecciono varios archivos (.pdf) y me los adjunte a mi envio de correo.

Comment: Hola Ever he actualizado mi respuesta con lo que necesitabas, y te deje una descripcion corta, no olvides calificarme como la respuesta a tu pregunta desde la flecha.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para enviar un archivo desde [PHP Mailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Tutorial#using-attachments) basta con la siguiente linea de código:

```
$mail->AddAttachment();
```

Ejemplo de envío de varios archivos:

```
$archivo1 = 'uploads/prueba.pdf';
$archivo2 = 'uploads/prueba.mp3';

$mail->AddAttachment($archivo1,$archivo2);
```

Por si lo que necesitas es enviarlos desde una url, lo puedes realizar de la siguiente manera:

```
$url = 'https://www.miweb.com/uploads/archivo.pdf'; //url ejemplo del archivo
$fichero = file_get_contents($url); //Aqui guardas el archivo temporalmente.
$mail->addStringAttachment($fichero, 'solicitud.pdf'); //aqui he usado addStringAttachment para enviar el archivo, en segunda instancia le doy un nombre.
```

**Aclaración**
En vez de utilizar distintas variables de `($archivo1, $archivo2, $archivo3)` puedes crear un array.

> ACTUALIZACIÓN

Debido a que me comentas que necesitas saber como enviar multiples archivos desde un formulario (input type file) actualizo mi respuesta.

En el formulario html:

```
<form action="dondeseenvian.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      Enviar estos ficheros:<br />
      <input multiple="true" name="archivos[]" type="file" /><br />
      <input type="submit" value="Enviar ficheros" />
    </form>
```

Si lo notas en el `input` tipo `file` incluí un atributo llamado `multiple="true"` lo que significa que te permite seleccionar varios archivos al mismo tiempo.

en el atributo `name` puedes percatarte de que utilice los corchetes `[]` los cuales me permiten enviar un `array list`.

En tu archivo donde se envia el correo (controlador)

```
<?php 
$archivos = $_FILES['archivos'];
$nombre_archivos = $archivos['name'];
$ruta_archivos = $archivos['tmp_name'];

require 'mailsend/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

    $mail = new PHPMailer;

    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Host = 'servidor@smtp.com';
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = 'usuario@smtp.com'; 
    $mail->Password = 'clavesmtp';
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
    $mail->Port = 587;

    $mail->setFrom('remitente@correo.com', 'Nombre remitente');
    $mail->addAddress('destinatario@correo.com');

    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
    $mail->Subject = 'Asunto archivos adjuntos';
    $mail->Body = "Adjuntos se encuentran los archivos";
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($ruta_archivos as $rutas_archivos) {
        $mail->AddAttachment($rutas_archivos,$nombre_archivos[$i]);
        $i++;
    }

    if(!$mail->send()) {
        echo 'Message could not be sent.';
        echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
        echo 'Message has been sent';
    }
 ?>
```

Recibi primeramente el archivo mediante `$_FILES` despues defini dos variables una para los nombres y una para la ruta temporal del archivo, en segunda instancia cree un ciclo foreach para multiplicar la linea  `$mail->AddAttachment($rutas_archivos,$nombre_archivos[$i]);` el numero de veces que exista un archivo.

Comment: Amigo y como hago para que envié todos los pdf desde mi base de datos sin necesidad de abrir para seleccionar multiples archivos??

Comment: @LenninJesús Aun lo necesitas?